# Laravel redirect to correct path on missing routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

In my application when user enter this url as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/showContent/aboutUs` laravel show error as an

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

for that correct path is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/showContent/aboutUs` and I'm trying to manage that and adding missing segment for that for example:

Route:

```
Route::get('{lang?}/showContent/aboutUs', array('as' => 'lang', 'uses' => 'HomeController@showAboutUsPage'))->where('lang', '.+');
```

mapping routes:

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    $locale = request()->segment(1);
    if ($locale != 'fa' && $locale != 'en') {
        $locale = 'fa';
    }
    app()->setLocale($locale);


    Route::middleware('web')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->prefix($locale)
        ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}
```

on `mapWebRoutes` function i'm using multi language and manage routes, and for missing parameters as language key on `segment(1)` I get error, now how can I add missing segment or manage routes to redirect to correct path?

Comment: it is related to your web server. you can use .htaccess file for that.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for duplicate comment!
it is related to your web server. you can use .htaccess file for that.
another way is to use exception handler. you can check the exception type and also the request route. then redirect to appropriate url if it  is necessary.

Comment: i'm not sure this solution can be resolve my problem, but i can solve that https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056158/1830228

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved:

i change `kernel.php` to :

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\Language::class,

    ...

];
```

and `Language` class to:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $locale = $request->segment(1);

    if (!array_key_exists($locale, config('app.locales'))) {
        $segments = $request->segments();
        array_unshift($segments,config('app.fallback_locale'));
        return redirect(implode('/', $segments));
    }

    app()->setLocale($locale);

    return $next($request);
}
```