# Laravel get data from belongsToMany relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

in my web site i have `Products` and `ProductCategories` which they are `belongsToMany` relationship, with

Controller:

```
$products = Products::paginate(10);
```

View:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    {{$product->productCategories}}
@endforeach
```

i have this result:

```
[{"id":6,"category_name":"\u062f\u0645 \u0646\u0648\u0634 \u0647\u0627","lang":"fa",
  "images":{"images":{"original":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/1513065012.jpeg"},
  "created_at":"2017-12-12 07:50:12",
  "updated_at":"2017-12-12 07:50:12","pivot":{"products_id":44,"product_categories_id":6}}]
```

now how can i access to `category_name` in this result?

this code don't work for me and i get error:

```
{{$product->productCategories->category_name}}
```

error:

```
Property [category_name] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

or

```
{{$product->productCategories['category_name']}}
```

error:

```
Undefined index: category_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over collection:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    @foreach($product->productCategories as $category)
        {{ $category->category_name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: hi man, thanks to help me again, could you help me on this topic?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/48043352/1830228